# XMLHttpRequest syntax for photos

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

According to google's chrome getting started tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

I am having difficulty understanding the source code for the javascript function that does the XHR request to grab photos from Flickr

```
requestKittens: function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", this.searchOnFlickr_, true);
    req.onload = this.showPhotos_.bind(this);
    req.send(null);
    },
```

I understand the syntax of req.open, req.send,etc. but why is the boolean true, this placeholder, and null inserted?  Are these necessary parameters for the request? Can anyone please explain this or refer to any resources that explain it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource is XMLHttpRequest [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/).

You can read there, that:

- open method has the following syntax: `open(method, url [, async = true [, username = null [, password = null]]])`
  As you can see: async argument is optional and it defaults to true. So in your example it can be easily omitted.
- send method, `send([data = null])`, takes optional argument providing request entity body. It defaults to null and is ignored when request method is GET (so in your case).